# How to translate a dockerfile into a XML for jib plugin of Maven, specially the "RUN" and "HEALTHCHECK" part?

Tags: docker, maven, health-check, jib

I have a dockerfile which is like:

```
# openjdk:11-jre include 'wget' and 'curl', while openjdk:11-jre-slim does not
FROM openjdk:11-jre

ENV VERSION=2.28.1
ENV DIR=/home/wiremock
ENV JAR=wiremock-jre8-standalone-$VERSION.jar
ENV FULLPATH=$DIR/$JAR

# grab wiremock standalone jar
RUN mkdir -p $DIR
RUN useradd --no-log-init -r wiremock
RUN wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock-jre8-standalone/$VERSION/$JAR \
        -O $FULLPATH
WORKDIR $DIR
# copy stub files to container
COPY --chown=wiremock:root src/main/resources/stubs/__files __files/
COPY --chown=wiremock:root src/main/resources/stubs/mappings mappings/
USER wiremock
EXPOSE 8080 8443
# healthcheck(wait 10s to start, then wait 10s interval and check, if wait more than 1s, is fail. Retry 3 times
# with same interval before marking as unhealthy)
HEALTHCHECK --start-period=10s --interval=10s --timeout=1s --retries=3 \
    CMD curl http://localhost:8080/__admin && curl -k https://localhost:8443/__admin || exit 1
CMD java -jar $FULLPATH --https-port 8443 --verbose
```

Now, I cannot find a proper way to do it with maven-jib-plugin.

The dependency will be copied as a dependency, not downloaded with `wget`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>${wiremock.standalone.version}</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I am not sure if all things can be done in jib, like creating user and so.

Now, I have this pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <docker.registry>xxx</docker.registry>
        <docker.base.image>${docker.registry}/base/openjdk11:latest</docker.base.image>
        <docker.image>app</docker.image>
        <https.port>8443</https.port>
        <work.dir>/home/wiremock</work.dir>
        <jar>wiremock-jre8-standalone-${wiremock.standalone.version}.jar</jar>
        <full.path>${work.dir}/${jar}</full.path>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.tomakehurst</groupId>
            <artifactId>wiremock-jre8-standalone</artifactId>
            <version>${wiremock.standalone.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/libs</outputDirectory>
                            <includeArtifactIds>wiremock-jre8-standalone</includeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>${docker.base.image}</image>
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>${docker.image}</image>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>latest</tag>
                        </tags>
                    </to>
                    <extraDirectories>
                        <paths>
                            <path>
                                <from>libs/</from>
                                <into>${work.dir}</into>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <from>src/main/resources/stubs/__files</from>
                                <into>${work.dir}/__files</into>
                            </path>
                            <path>
                                <from>src/main/resources/stubs/mappings</from>
                                <into>${work.dir}/mappings</into>
                            </path>
                        </paths>
                        <permissions>
                            <permission>
                                <file>${work.dir}/**/*.*</file>
                                <mode>744</mode>
                            </permission>
                        </permissions>
                    </extraDirectories>
                    <container>
                        <user>wiremock:root</user>
                        <appRoot>${work.dir}</appRoot>
                        <workingDirectory>${work.dir}</workingDirectory>
                        <ports>
                            <port>8080</port>
                            <port>${https.port}</port>
                        </ports>
                        <args> <!-- dockerfile CMD part-->
                            <arg>-jar</arg>
                            <arg>${full.path}</arg>
                            <arg>--https-port</arg>
                            <arg>${https.port}</arg>
                            <arg>--verbose</arg>
                        </args>
                        <mainClass>com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner</mainClass>
                    </container>
                    <!-- <containerizingMode>packaged</containerizingMode> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run `mvn jib:dockerBuild`, the image is built successfully(good news!), I see in log the dependency jar is copied to `libs`, and then copied into container.

But then when I run it, I see error:

```sh
docker: Error response from daemon: unable to find user wiremock: no matching entries in passwd file.
```

So jib did not create the user for me.

Also, I think HEALTHCHECK is not done, neither.

I can skip new user creation and healthcheck, as they are not recommended and not supported now(https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/676, https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/1029), but when I want to run the jar like I do in dockerfile, I see another error:

```sh
$ docker run  -p 8080:8080 -p 8443:8443 app
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: j is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.validateOptionCharacters(OptionParser.java:633)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionCluster(OptionParser.java:528)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleShortOptionToken(OptionParser.java:523)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:59)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.CommandLineOptions.<init>(CommandLineOptions.java:179)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner.run(WireMockServerRunner.java:52)
        at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner.main(WireMockServerRunner.java:134)
```

I see the image is built like this:

```
[INFO] Container entrypoint set to [java, -cp, @/home/wiremock/jib-classpath-file, com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.standalone.WireMockServerRunner]
[INFO] Container program arguments set to [-jar, /home/wiremock/wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.28.1.jar, --https-port, 8443, --verbose]
```

How can I properly translate this dockerfile into a jib configuration in XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, at last I found it:

I should set `<container><entrypoint>`, and not `<args>`. `<mainClass>` is not needed.

```
<container>
    ...
    <entrypoint>java,-jar,${full.path},--https-port,${https.port},--verbose</entrypoint>
</container>
<!--  <containerizingMode>packaged</containerizingMode>-->
```

Then the entrypoint is like:

```
[INFO] Container entrypoint set to [java, -jar, /home/wiremock/wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.28.1.jar, --https-port, 8443, --verbose]
```

And the wiremock jar is running correctly.